# How to implement firebase recycler using TextWatcher?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I have implemented Firebase recycler in my app. Everything works fine while using text watcher, but recycler view is not updating in `onTextChanged` with the keyboard up, and gets updated as soon as i press the keyboard to go down.

This is my code:

```
private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {
            if(s.toString().trim().length()<1)
            {
                mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else
            {
                mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                firebaseSearch(s.toString());
            }
            Toast.makeText(ChooseUser.this,s.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
```

This is firebase recycler:

```
private void firebaseSearch(String searchText)
    {
        Query firebaseSearchQuery = databaseReference
                .orderByChild("Name")
                .startAt(searchText.toLowerCase())
                .endAt(searchText.toLowerCase() + "\uf8ff");

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Users> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Users>()
                    .setQuery(firebaseSearchQuery, snapshot ->
                            new Users(snapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString(),
                            snapshot.child("Image").getValue().toString(),
                                    snapshot.getKey(),
                                    snapshot.child("Profile").getValue().toString()
                            ))
                    .build();

        firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder>(
                options
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Users model) {

                    holder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getName(), model.getImage());

            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.search_list_items, parent, false);

                return new UsersViewHolder(view);
            }
        };
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
```

Is there anything to change in my code to update the view dynamically as I enter the words and to show recycler when the keyboard is up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just that, I was having `mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);` in my code.
Removing this made it work.